# Is this subset a closure?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given the following subset of $(Z_{50}, *)$:

$K = \{\overline{3}n\ /\ n \in Z\}$

And $*$ is defined as follows: $\forall \overline{a},\overline{b} \in Z_{50}, \  \overline{a} * \overline{b} = \overline{a} + \overline{b} + \overline{ab}$

Is $K$ a closure of $Z_{50}$ under the operation $*$? If so, why? Can you explain the most easy way a beginner like me can understand? Thank you! :)

Comment: What is a closure of $\mathbf Z_{50}$? Would you mean $K$ is closed in  $\mathbf Z_{50}$ for the `*` operation?

Comment: Yes, sorry, English is not my native language so I had to search for a translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe first that $K$ can also be described as 
$$\{\bar 3\,\bar n\mid \bar n\in \mathbf Z_{50}\}.$$
Then, if $\bar a=\bar 3\,\bar h$,  $\,\bar b=\bar3\,\bar k$ :
$$\bar a*\bar b=\bar 3\,\bar h+\bar3\,\bar k+\bar 9\,\bar h\,\bar k=\bar 3(\bar h+\bar k+\bar 3\,\bar h\,\bar k)\in K.$$

Comment: Thank you. What I don't understand is why $\{\bar 3\,\bar n\mid \bar n\in \mathbf Z_{50}\}.$? We've said that $n \in Z$.

Comment: Yes, but if $n=m+50k\; 0\le m<50$, $3n=3m+3\cdot 50 k\equiv 3m\mod 50$. So all $n$s in the same congruence class will give the same result.

Comment: Why is $n = m + 50k$?

Comment: II suppose $n$ and $m$ are in the same congruence class, and I show $\bar 3 n=\bar 3 m$. Hence the result depends only on the congruence class.